# Can I install 64-bit Windows 7 on a Dell Vostro 1700 laptop?

Tags: windows, 64-bit

The processor is reported as being an Intel Duo T7250.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried it out, and it works fine. I didn't need to get any drivers.

My Windows Experience is rated as 1.0 for graphics which may mean that the Standard VGA Graphics Adapter reported in Device Manager could be improved on (...?) but things are working  well for my modest needs.

Answer (score 5):

You can install it, but that doesn't mean all of the associated peripherals will work correctly **or at all***. It appears that the Vostro 1700 only has [drivers for 32-bit operating systems](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&ServiceTag=&SystemID=VOS_N_1700&os=WLH&osl=en&catid=&impid=). 64-bit versions may be available from elsewhere but **the only way to know for sure is test.**

Unless you want to risk having to reinstall your machine regardless, you could repartition your drive and run your original OS alongside Windows 7. Once everything checks out, delete the the original OS and resize the partition.

*Advice from someone that's been down this road with a Sony VAIO with unsatisfactory results.

Answer (score 1):

Use [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html), look for 64-bit instruction set:

> CPU-Z is a freeware that gathers information on some of the main
>   devices of your system.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [T7250](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819111328) is a Core 2 Duo, which is a 64-bit CPU. It will support Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 0):

Your T7250 CPU supports the Intel EMT64 tech.

[Intel Processor Spec Finder](http://processorfinder.intel.com/Default.aspx)

So... yes you can!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. A quick [Google](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=31728) will find you the answer you're looking for.

I am running it on my laptop w/ 1.5 GB of RAM. and it's doing OK. I would suggest jamming as much ram as possible into your machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the latest Windows 7 x64 drivers for Geforce 8x00m GS/GT (depending on which 1700 you have) and then your graphics score should definitely improve! Getting 5.8 for graphics on Vostro 1700 with 8600m GT video. Get them from www.nvidia.com

Regarding the processor... the T7250 is standard but optional is anything between that and T7700.

Comment: Thanks, Nvidia have a great little ActiveX scanner which found the correct driver for me! I'd upvote you if I could... Pete.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Vostro 1700 and I am running Win 7 64-bit. Most if not all programs seem to work fine. Video drivers downloaded directly from nvidia.com.